# Securing a string before exec()ing it

Tags: php, security, shell-exec

I have a PHP app which takes a user-inputted $imageurl and does the following:

```
exec('convert "'.$url.'" -thumbnail 80x500 "images/out.jpg"');
```

Now obviously I have to take some precautions with this to stop users from executing arbitrary code. For example, if the user sets `$url` to`";rm -rf *;"` is no good at all.

So for starters I have to filter out `"` so that no matter what they type in, they can't escape from their input being a parameter to `convert`. But should I filter out `;` as well? I've seen urls with semicolons in them... and while the semicolon is really the danger here, filtering out `"` would still keep me safe right? But can urls have `"` in them? And are there any other characters I should watch for?

Maybe instead of filtering characters out I should try to escape them. So should I try to escape every character interpreted specially by the shell? Or just escape `"` as everything else is sort of "pre-escaped" given that it's inside double-quotes?

Sorry for my rambling confusion, I'm just new at this and want to stay safe!

Thanks,
Mala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to make sure the URL is a URL, use [filter_var](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

This will not prevent people from supplying a URL like `example.com/foo?;rm -rf` though, which is still a valid URL. I'm not sure if this would cause `rm` to execute, but you could also check the URL with [`parse_url()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and omit the query part.

Generally, it is a good idea to have a look at these as well:

- [escapeshellarg()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) — Escape a string to be used as a shell argument
- [escapeshellcmd()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) — Escape shell metacharacters

Also see the [PHP Manual on securing user input](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/security.variables.php).

Comment: I can't omit the query part as some sites serve there images via script.php?image=something.jpg

Comment: Then just use filter_var and the shell escape function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions to ensure that $url only contains valid filename characters, e.g. "(\w\.\-/){1,256}". Plus, I imagine you are renaming the file the user uploads to be a random filename, or at least a whitelisted filename (i.e. using the same regex). *sha1*.ext or *md5*.ext are easy formats to use.